# Elasticsearch index doesn't have field with analyzer?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have an ES index with a mapping like this:

```
{'texts-temp': {'aliases': {},
  'mappings': {'properties': {'data': {'properties':
       (...)
       'user_text': {'type': 'text',
             'fields': {'word_tokenized': {'type': 'text',
                         'analyzer': 'text_analyzer'}}},
       (...)
     },
    'settings': {'index': {'number_of_shards': '1',
          'provided_name': 'texts-temp',
          'creation_date': (...),
    'analysis': {'filter': {'shingen_filter': {'max_shingle_size': '3',
       'min_shingle_size': '2',
       'type': 'shingle'}},
     'analyzer': {'text_analyzer': {'filter': ['lowercase',
        'stop',
        'asciifolding',
        'apostrophe',
        'stemmer',
        'shingen_filter'],
       'type': 'custom',
       'tokenizer': 'standard'}}},
```

When I do the following search:

```
search = Search(index = 'texts-temp')
q = Q("terms", data__urls=list_urls_text)
search = search.query(q)
search = search.extra(track_total_hits=True)
reply = search.execute()
[x.data.user_text.word_tokenized for x in reply]
```

I get an empty list... However, if I look at the elements x.data.user_text, then I get the texts, but not tokenized.

What am I doing wrong that the index doesn't have the field data.user_text.word_tokenized?

The JSON body of the search above is the following:

```
{'query': {'terms': {'data.urls': list_urls_text}},
 'track_total_hits': True}
```

Comment: Did you try this request in kibana? Or can you provide final json body that will be sent to search (results of python lib)?

Comment: @AlexBaidan I've just edited the question, and added the JSON body. ;)